# Return type of boost::accumulator::tag::mean

Tags: c++, boost, types

Please consider the following Boost.Accumulator example where `value_type` is an integral type:

```
typedef boost::accumulators::features <
        boost::accumulators::tag::sum
      , boost::accumulators::tag::min
      , boost::accumulators::tag::max
      , boost::accumulators::tag::mean
> Features;

typedef boost::accumulators::accumulator_set <
       value_type
      , Features
> Accumulator;
```

However, extracting values from the `accumulator_set` makes sense for `min`, `max`, and `sum` and the return types are clear. What about the type for (`accu` is a variable):

```
boost::accumulator::extract_result < tag::mean > ( accu );
```

I guess the type is `double`. How is the type deduced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My interest was piqued by this so I followed it through in the boost source code.

I created an Accumulator with value_type = int. The result of extract_result is indeed a double.

This is deduced within extract_result<> by this line:

```
typename mpl::apply<AccumulatorSet, Feature>::type::result_type
```

which in turn depends on this line:

```
typedef typename numeric::functional::fdiv<Sample, std::size_t>::result_type result_type;
```

(where Sample is an int)

which is partially specialised here to force ints into doubles when dividing:

```
// partial specialization that promotes the arguments to double for
// integral division.
template<typename Left, typename Right>
struct fdiv_base<Left, Right, typename enable_if<are_integral<Left, Right> >::type>
  : functional::divides<double const, double const>
{};
```

sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics.hpp>

typedef boost::accumulators::features <
boost::accumulators::tag::sum
, boost::accumulators::tag::min
, boost::accumulators::tag::max
, boost::accumulators::tag::mean
> Features;

typedef boost::accumulators::accumulator_set <
int
, Features
> Accumulator;


using namespace std;



int main()
{
    Accumulator acc;
    acc(0);
    acc(99);


    auto mean = boost::accumulators::extract_result < boost::accumulators::tag::mean > (acc);
    cout << "mean is " << mean << " of type " << typeid(mean).name() << endl;

}
```

EDIT:

examining:

```
typename mpl::apply<AccumulatorSet, Feature>::type::result_type
```

`AccumulatorSet` is our accumulator (deduced from argument to `extract_result`)
`Feature` is `tag::mean`
`tag::mean` exports `impl` which is an `impl::mean_impl<mpl::_1, sum>`

The `extract_result` function calls `find_accumulator<Feature>(acc)` which returns a reference to a `mpl::apply<Feature>::type` (a function object which takes an accumulator as a parameter)

calling result() on this object calls against mean's impl(_1) where _1 is the sum(accumulator), from where the mean_impl can extract the sample_type where it is used in type deduction for the parameters to fdiv<>.

Unfortunately, template metafunctions are hard to write, and even harder to read!

Comment: I can't follow `apply`'s dependency upon `typedef typename numeric::functional::fdiv<Sample, std::size_t>::result_type result_type;` can you help me out?

Comment: I am on pins and needles.

Comment: @JonathanMee what does that mean?

Comment: it means he can't sit still (misplaced excitement while waiting for my sorry attempt at an explanation)

Comment: @sehe It means that I wanted to read the edit that [Richard Hodges](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2015579/richard-hodges) just posted and I was scared he forgot about me. http://english.stackexchange.com/a/205916/85230

Comment: The bottom line is that the `mean` implementation depends on the expansion of the template function object `fdiv<>` which is prevented from instantiating versions where the parameters are integral, forcing integers to be promoted to doubles.